# Old Windows Installers for python library fiona

Tags: python, fiona

Due the the recent bug as presented [here](https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona/issues/80) for fiona 1.1, i am obliged to use a version of fiona in 1.0.x on windows 8.1. however, i can't find older versions of the installer at [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#fiona).

Are there any sources for the archive installers, specifically for the 32bit fiona (1.0.x) ? thanks in advance!

P.S.

I think it will apply to ALL other previous libraries, and not just fiona

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this, which seems very intuitive, is email the maintainer himself (Christophe Gohlke) together with a bug report on fiona's github site. If ther is indeed a bug he wil upload the latest working versions.

Dr. Gohlke replied within 8 hours and Sean Gilles ( creator of Fiona) did, too.

Answer (score 0):

If you're into package managers Enthought Canopy can install fiona 1.0.2

Comment: thanks for the tip. i might try it again if there's no other choice. i would double check if it's part of the "free" packages included.

Comment: It is, I have the free version.  I think it's a great way of managing python packages on Windows, which is so overly difficult IMO.